How do you generate good questions given an answer with the gpt2-large model provided by the Hugging Face Community
I am trying to make a QA data set to train my own model on. The answers are derived from publicly released USAF Technical Orders. After parsing the documents the excerpts are in the following format:
Title=TO 00-5-18
Section=11.2.3.3
Excerpt=If the TO number has four basic groups, the third group contains one or more numeric characters representing
model, type or PN assigned to speciﬁc equipment and the speciﬁc types of TOs are then identiﬁed in group four.

However when we pass these to our model we are either the prompt repeated, a non-sense answer, or it will talk to itself about how it is not doing what was asked of it. Once in a blue moon we will get a valid question, but since the generated qa pairs will be used to train a different model they need to be of a much higher quality. We don't have the time or resources to manually verify all generated questions.
Here is one example of a response:
Question:
 A bad question is not relevant to the text and is a non-sequitur. If you need to provide a question that is a complete sentence, please provide a question that is a sentence. If you need to provide a question that is not a sentence, please provide a question that is not a sentence. If you need to provide multiple questions, please provide them in the order you want them.

The following questions are not applicable to the AEROSPACE EQUIPMENT technical order
Answer:
TO 00-20-1
1.1.1.1
Unless otherwise specified, the term AEROSPACE EQUIPMENT in this technical order refers to weapon systems and equipment

Here are some example prompts we have tried:
prompt = f"Formulate a clear and concise QUESTION that can be answered based on the following text: {section['Excerpt']}. A good question is a complete sentence and is relevant to the text. A good question can be answered by the text verbatum"

prompt = f"What would be the question asked to recieve a response that is the following text: {section['Excerpt']}. You will provide only one question that can be directly answered by {section['Excerpt']} Only provide a question that would make sense if it ends with a question mark. A good question is strictly relevant to the text and is a complete sentence."

prompt = """Formulate a clear, concise, and relevant question that can be answered by the Text below. A good question is a question. A good question is a single complete sentence. A good question is relevant to the Text. A good question can be answered by the Text verbatim. The question should be formulated based on the verbs and nouns of the Text. A good question does not include the entire Text.
Text: """ + section['Excerpt']

We only want it to formulate a question based on the excerpt so we are not providing the title or section the excerpt came from.
Below is an example of parameters we have set for the model:
output = textGenerator(prompt,
                       max_new_tokens=100,
                       temperature=0.74,
                       top_p=0.87,
                       num_return_sequences=1,
                       do_sample=True,
                       pad_token_id=self.qaGenTokenizer.eos_token_id,
                       return_full_text=False)

We are at a loss on how to proceed with this and any tips, advice, or fixes would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance.

GPT2 is not instruction tuned, so it will not follow the instructions properly. You should use those instruction-tuned models, such as https://huggingface.co/models?search=instruct .
